# Count the number of times that the number '13' appears at least once in an n digit number

Tags: combinatorics

*Edited question to provide more information and clarity. See original question at the bottom for reference.*

My end goal is to count how many times '13' appears in an n-digit number at least once. This means that a number like 21313 would count as only 1. I created a similar question (which is linked to this one I believe) where I received help to obtain the total number of times '13' appears in an n-digit number (where a number like 21313 would count as 2).
I realized that if I take the total number of times 13 appears and I subtract the number of times it's "repeated" (where in a number like 131313 I consider the number of "repetitions" to be 2), I get the total number of times that 13 appears at least once in that n-digit number.
I say "repetition" because I'm not counting all the number of times it's repeated, but the number of additional times that 13 shows up in a number. This is why in a number like 131313, I don't say there's 3 "repetitions." I'm saying that the first '13' shows up once and then the 2nd and 3rd 13's are 2 extra '13's.
I created this question to help me understand how to count those repetitions (see original question below for more information).
I'm not sure if this is the best way to solve this problem, but it's what makes the most sense for now. Please let me know if there's other/better ways to solve it as I've been discovering multiple methods to solve similar problems and would love to know more about the subject).

For reference, here's the values I've obtained using a code I wrote to help solve the problem. Note: I'm including 0 in the first digit of an n-digit number so that I can account for all of the values from 0 up to the highest number in that n-digit number (meaning in a 3 digit number, I'm looking at all the numbers from 0 to 999).

```
| # Digits | Total # Times 13 Appears | # "Repetitions" | Total # Times 13 Appears at Least Once |
|----------|--------------------------|---------------|----------------------------------------|
| 1        | 0                        | 0             | 0                                      |
| 2        | 1                        | 0             | 1                                      |
| 3        | 20                       | 0             | 20                                     |
| 4        | 300                      | 1             | 299                                    |
| 5        | 4000                     | 30            | 3970                                   |
| 6        | 50000                    | 599           | 49401                                  |
| 7        | 600000                   | 9960          | 590040                                 |
| 8        | 7000000                  | 149001        | 6850999                                |
```

Original Question:
I'm trying to find the number of times the number '13' is repeated in an n-digit number.

For example:
For a 2 digit number, the answer is 0 because 13 is present only once and it's not repeated.
For a 3 digit number, the answer is also 0 because your only possibilities are _ 13 or 13_. You'd need at least 4 digits to see 13 more than once.
For 4 digits, the only possibility is 1313, and in this example I would count this as 1 repetition. (I am not trying to count the number of times that 13 appears which would be 2 for 1313, I just want how many times it can be repeated).
For 5 digits, you can have 1313_ or 13_13 or _1313. For this, I can fill each _ with 10 possibilities for a total of 10+10+10 = 30. In this case, I am allowing 0 to be the first digit, meaning I would like to count 01313 as part of the 5 digit number.
After 5 digits is where I get stuck. I wrote a program to give me the answers but I don't understand how to mathematically obtain them:

6 digits: 599
7 digits: 9960
8 digits: 149001

I see a trend that for 4 digits, you subtract 1 (where the answer is 600-1). For 8 digits, you add 1 (ans = 149000 +1), and I'm guessing that trend keeps repeating but I don't understand why that is.
Could someone please explain how to work this out? Thank you!

Comment: What is 599 counting? You can't possibly mean that there's a 6-digit number with 13 repeated 599 times in it...

Comment: @MishaLavrov: I _think_ he means that there are 599 six-digit strings that each contains `13` as a substring exactly (or at least?) twice. That is not the _correct_ count under either interpretation, though.

Comment: (More precisely, $6\cdot 100$ will count the string `131313` three times, so depending on whether you want to count it at all, the answer should be either $597$ or $598$).

Comment: Maybe we want to count the total number of times `13` repeats (that is, occurs for the second or more time) over all the $6$-digit strings? Then we'd count `131313` twice and get $599$. I really don't like playing the guessing game with questions, so I'll leave this for now unless the question is edited to clarify.

Comment: "in an n-digit number" ? If we do not know the number, we cannot know how many times "$13$" occurs (or how often it is repeated). Do you mean the MAXIMUM number of times $13$ can be repeated in an $n$-digit number ?

Comment: For $n$ digit numbers, for each number of "$13$"s that can appear in that number, solve a [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) problem for inserting extra digits among the "$13$"s.

Comment: I think your first sentence should be "In how many n-digit numbers appears '13' at least once". An therefore your title  is  wrong, too.

Comment: Yes, the title should also be changed after the update to the question; the title currently reflects the original version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your ultimate goal is to count the number of length-$n$ strings that contain `13` at least once, counting the number of repeats is not going to help; it is strictly harder.

Instead, let $a_n$ be the number of length-$n$ strings that *don't* contain `13` at all. There is a recurrence $$a_n = 10 a_{n-1} - a_{n-2}$$ justified as follows: to any of the $a_{n-1}$ strings of length $n-1$ with no `13`, we  may append any of $10$ digits, except for $a_{n-2}$ cases in which the result is a string ending in `13` (but with no other occurrences of `13` in it).

Together with the base cases $a_1 = 10$ and $a_2 = 99$, this gives a shifted version of the [OEIS sequence A004189](https://oeis.org/A004189). From there, or from standard tricks for linear recurrences, we can find $$a_n = \frac{(5 + 2\sqrt 6)^{n+1} - (5-2\sqrt 6)^{n+1}}{4 \sqrt 6}.$$

The number of length-$n$ strings that *do* contain `13` at least once, then, is given by $10^n - a_n$.

---

If you still want to count the number of "repeat occurrences of `13`" (that is, the number of times over all length-$n$ strings that `13` appears in a string not for the first time), then this can be done in terms of $a_n$; it won't help us find $a_n$.

The total number of `13`'s that appear in these strings is $(n-1)10^{n-2}$: there are $n-1$ places we could put a `13`, and $10^{n-2}$ places to choose all the other digits. This counts a string with $k$ occurrences of `13` $k$ times; we want to count it $k-1$ times. So we may subtract the previously found $10^n - a_n$ to get the formula
$$
   (n-1)10^{n-2} - 10^n + a_n.
$$

Comment: Thank you so much!!! This took a while to understand but I finally got there. I had a question though: how did you think to count the number of n-length strings that don't have the number '13'? Did you know this would have a recurrence? I guess I was trying to find a recurrence with my method and couldn't and I would have never thought to count the number of times '13' didn't appear

Comment: It was similar to problems I'd seen before; it's also often worth trying to take the complement even if you see no immediate reason for it to work. There's also some intuition for it here: if we take a random very long string, it will almost certainly have the number $13$, so the number of length-$n$ strings that do contain $13$ will be close to $10^n$ for large $n$. This makes it likely that it has the form $10^n - a_n$ for some simpler-to-express $a_n$.